# Use helper select or select_tag with JSON on Rails 3.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

How can I use a json with select or select_tag in Rails ?

In my controller I make a call to some url and retrieve some data in json format (only two columns, :id :name)

In my view file, I want to use the helper tag select or select_tag to use this json to fill it, but I'm having errors or wrong data

thanks

```
[{"id":"197630", "name":"JOHN PERS"} , {"id":"6", "name":"JOSHUA JOSH"}]
```

also I've tried to decode the json with this code

```
    @parsed_json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(@listJson)
```

but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if `@list_json` is a real json we can do this:

```
<% collection = options_for_select(ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(@list_json).map { |b| [b["name"], b["id"]] }) %>
<%= f.select :name, collection %>
```